# I want result set to be only the latest login per staff

Tags: sql

This table contains all the login data of staff. I would like to report on only the latest by date i only want to show in this case:
this is the data result of the below: I am only interested in 3/8/2021|3/8/2021|Korner|Altor|

| session_start | session_end | last_name | first_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/27/2021 | 2/27/2021 | Korner | Altor |
| 2/25/2021 | 2/25/2021 | Korner | Altor |
| 2/24/2021 | 2/24/2021 | Korner | Altor |
| 3/3/2021 | 3/4/2021 | Korner | Altor |
| 3/1/2021 | 3/3/2021 | Korner | Altor |
| 3/8/2021 | 3/8/2021 | Korner | Altor |

```
select a.session_start, a.session_end, b.last_name, b.first_name
from use_log_with_transactions_view a
inner join staff_view b
  on a.staff_id = b.staff_id
order by b.last_name, b.first_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to have last, that would be maximum value for a session date, so you need to use `max` and `group by`:

```
select 
    max(a.session_start) as session_start, 
    max(a.session_end) as session_end, 
    b.last_name, 
    b.first_name 
from use_log_with_transactions_view a
inner join staff_view b
   on a.staff_id = b.staff_id
group by b.last_name, b.first_name
order by b.last_name, b.first_name
```

Comment: The output might contain values from different rows, see [DBIFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58bcc2b5dc0b5af1fa0e268f7d2a6f4d)

Comment: Based on the input from OP the scenario you mentioned is not possible (that one user can have 2 parallel sessions active)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest session_start for all users.
Then you could use the ROW_NUMBER function.
If the version of your database supports it.

```
select 
 log.session_start, 
 log.session_end, 
 staff.last_name, 
 staff.first_name
from (
   select t.*,
   row_number() over (partition by staff_id order by session_start desc) as rn
   from use_log_with_transactions_view t
) log
join staff_view as staff
  on staff.staff_id = log.staff_id
where log.rn = 1
```

But for only 1 user it's simple.
If you order descending by session_start for the staff, then take the top 1.

In MS Sql Server you can `select top 1 ...` 
In MySql you can use LIMIT 1

```
select 
 log.session_start, 
 log.session_end, 
 staff.last_name, 
 staff.first_name 
from use_log_with_transactions_view as log
join staff_view as staff
  on staff.staff_id = log.staff_id
where staff.last_name = 'Korner' 
  and staff.first_name = 'Altor' 
order by log.session_start desc
limit 1
```

Comment: This wouldn't work with more people. This way it's limited to a single person

Comment: right it should be for multiple staff, everyone's latest logn date,